# String Replace Regex like mustache js for Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, regex, webrick

I am new to ruby and was trying to make a simple function that would take a file and replace all the mustache with an array. For example:

### simple.tpl

```
<p>Hello {{person_name}}</p>
<p>{{welcome_msg}}</p>
```

I want to change it with an array of keys and values.

```
class Template

    attr_accessor :file_name

    def parse_template (array_to_replace)
        str = File.read(file_name)

        array_to_replace.each do |item|
        # required code here ...
        end

        return str
    end

end
```

Can anyone put the required code ???

### Expected Output

I don't know how multidimensional arrays work in ruby but what I want is:

```
the_arr = Array(
   :person_name => "John Doe",
   :welcome_msg => "Hello friend"
)
object = Template.new
object.file_name = "simple.tpl"
output = object.parse_template(the_arr);

puts output
```

### I should get

```
<p>Hello John Doe</p>
<p>Hello friend</p>
```

Comment: show your expected output..

Comment: You should probably work through a basic Ruby tutorial first.

Comment: ummm why? do I have so many errors in my code?

Comment: I'm saying that because of the `Array()` syntax you use. It is very uncommon and shows that you haven't really tried learning Ruby, you are just translating PHP syntax to Ruby Syntax. However, learning Ruby requires not only learning the syntax, but you will probably have to catch up on some new concepts as well. What you probably wanted is a `Hash`, which any basic ruby tutorial will cover in the first sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `mustache` gem](https://github.com/mustache/mustache):

```
require 'mustache'

attributes = {
  :person_name => "John Doe",
  :welcome_msg => "Hello friend"
}

template = File.read('simple.tpl')

output = Mustache.render(template, attributes)

puts output
# <p>Hello John Doe</p>
# <p>Hello friend</p>
```

Comment: `attributes = {
  :person_name => "John Doe",
  :welcome_msg => "Hello friend"
}` is this an array or object??

Comment: @Anonymous it's a hash and also an object

Comment: You've encountered another property of Ruby: _everything_ is an object.

Comment: how would we retrieve the value of say `:person_name` ? Like `attributes.person_name` ??

Comment: `attributes[:person_name]`

Comment: @Anonymous `attributes[:person_name]`, see the [`Hash` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html)

Comment: I hate to repeat myself, but you should really read a tutorial!

Comment: Yes it is an object, which has the `[]` method implemented ;-)

Comment: Here is a fun way to do your first steps in Ruby: http://tryruby.org/, an entire list of resources is available here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/

Comment: Ok thank you very much but can you tell me how to install mustache. I mean where to put that github folder for `require 'mustache'` to work

Comment: I have two files in a folder index.rb and simple.tpl

Comment: You need to install it with rubygems. Just enter `gem install mustache` on the command line. You do not need to download the source manually. Again, do the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in what is built in to Ruby.

```
string = '<p>Hello %{person_name}</p>
          <p>%{welcome_msg}</p>'

attributes = {
  :person_name => "John Doe",
  :welcome_msg => "Hello friend"
}

puts string % attributes
```

Output:

```html
<p>Hello John Doe</p>
<p>Hello friend</p>
```

Explanation:

The [String class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html) defines a method named `%` (yes, in Ruby you can have non-alphanumeric characters in method names). This does template-style replacement of `%{key}` with the values from a hash. It can also do formatting of numbers and strings; see the [documentation of the `%` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-25) for more information.

Comment: what is `%` symbol for??

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: Yes I know ... But the previous answer was better. Anyways, you have 19.k repu.. WHat else do you want ;) Thanks anyway

Comment: @Anonymous SO is not about accumulating as much rep as possible, it's about finding the best possible answer. You should accept the answer that answers your question the best and/or solves your problem in the best possible way – sometimes that is a post that does not answer the question directly, but rather tries to come up with an alternative approach that solves the same problem much more elegantly.

Comment: Thanks @p11y you are correct, it's not about the rep, it's about the answer that is the most helpful. He found the mustache gem (your answer) to be the best solution for his needs, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, I merely wanted to point that out so he won't accept answers based on "who needs the reputation most" in the future ;-)